# Using jQuery animation with angular's ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to use jQuery animation with angular's `ngAnimate` module. In particular, for this example, jQuery's `fadeIn` and `fadeOut`. I can get this to work with css transitions, using `.ng-enter` and `.ng-leave` etc, but for some reason, not jQuery.

The fade in for the following angular code does not work. The element just shows up straight away.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.toggle = true;
  }
]);

app.animation('.toggle', function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      element.fadeIn(1000, done);
    },
    leave: function(element, done) {
      element.fadeOut(1000, done);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="data.toggle = ! data.toggle">
    Toggle Button
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default toggle" ng-if="data.toggle">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Content being toggled
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, when using the same fade functions with just jQuery, the animation works fine:

```js
$(function() {
  var container = $('.container');
  var btn = $('.btn');
  var panel = $('.panel');
  var animating = false;

  btn.on('click', function() {
    if (animating)
      return;

    if (panel.is(':visible')) {
      animating = true;
      panel.fadeOut(1000, function() {
        animating = false;
        panel.remove();
      });
      return;
    }

    animating = true;
    panel.appendTo(container).fadeIn(1000, function() {
      animating = false
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="btn btn-primary">
    Toggle Button
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default toggle">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Content being toggled
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note, in both cases the panel element is being removed/ added to the DOM. I'm doing this in jQuery to mimic `ng-if` behaviour.

Is there a way to use jQuery animiations when angular adds an element to the DOM via `ng-if`? If it's possible with `ng-show` that would be even better. I don't need workarounds not using jQuery, I can figure those out myself. The answer must use jQuery animations. A small bit of css to support the jQuery animation is fine, however.

Comment: Why are you using jQuery, if you're using Angular?  Especially if you can get it to work in Angular already?

Comment: If I can get it to work using jQuery, then I can use the plethora of jQuery animations and libraries available.

Comment: Anything you can do in jQuery, you can do in Angular.

Comment: If that's the case, perhaps you can give me an answer that provides effects similar to those such as `slideUp` `slideDown`, `Blind`, `Bounce`, or indeed any effect from http://jqueryui.com/effect/ without having to create the code for those off the shelf effects.

Comment: ngAnimate can do those things with css transitions.

Comment: @ChrisStanley So where would I find, off the shelf, all of those transitions, transformations, @keyframes combined with the necessary JavaScript to work in sync with ngAnimate? For example, give me on off the shelf `explode` effect that works with ngAnimate. I'll happily accept your answer if you can prove what you're saying. ie any jQuery animation can simply be done with ngAnimate.

Comment: Ok.  You got me.  While I could create a directive that uses explode functionality, it would be long; however, besides that one single thing, ngAnimate can do all the other jQuery UI effects.

Comment: @ChrisStanley Ok. Keep it simple. Can you fade in without using css such as `.ng-enter` and `.ng-enter-active` with a `transition` on the element i.e. use already available `angularJS` or `ngAnimate` methods only?

Comment: Actually, W3Schools has a good tutorial on the simplicity of transitions:  http://www.w3schools.com/angular/tryit.asp?filename=try_ng_animation

Comment: @ChrisStanley thx.

Comment: Example of using jQuery animation in agular docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate#javascript-based-animations

Comment: I was looking for that for like an hour and couldn't find it.  Funny.  Glad you got to it on your own!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you insert an element using angular.js, it uses whatever styles you have set in your CSS and then executes your animation function. Using `.fadeIn()` on an element that's already visible [does nothing](https://jsfiddle.net/k5Lyywwn/). If you want to fade it in, you need to first set its `display` property to `none` in either your css:

```
.toggle{
    display: none;
}
```

...or in your animation function before fading it in:

```
element.css("display","none").fadeIn(1000, done);
```

Here's a working code:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.toggle = true;
  }
]);

app.animation('.toggle', function() {
  return {
    enter: function(element, done) {
      element.css("display","none").fadeIn(1000, done);
    },
    leave: function(element, done) {
      element.fadeOut(1000, done);
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.0/angular-animate.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <div class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="data.toggle = ! data.toggle">
    Toggle Button
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default toggle" ng-if="data.toggle">
    <div class="panel-body">
      Content being toggled
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was the conclusion I came to after a night's sleep, and was about to add it as the answer, but you beat me to it. :) Many thanks. +1 and accepted.